# How to improve Dijkstra algorithm for single source single-target shortest path?

Tags: dijkstra, single-source

what improvement can be made in given image dijkstra algorithm to improve Dijkstra algorithm for single source single-target shortest path?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5ZW6.png

Comment: This site is not for posting pictures of what is obviously your homework. That said. Dijkstra's algorithm is very famous and well documented. You should find this page useful http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/

Answer (score 1):

Improvement can be made in this  way:

when you visit a node again and no node weight is updating. then one can say there is no need traverse all the node. you can stop the traversing before visiting all the nodes in loop.